# Progress bar that closes window when complete

Tags: python

I'm Trying to have a progress bar window show up once a button is pressed and then close once the bar reaches the end (3 seconds), however it seems that the window doesn't generate till everything is done, hence why the button sleeps for 3 seconds instead of generating the Bar first. How can I get this to work? The Code is in 3 separate functions for ease of understanding the problem. Thanks in advance :)

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import Progressbar
from time import sleep

def Generate_Invoice(toplevel):
    Generating_Label=Label(toplevel, text="Please wait while we generate your invoice...")
    progress = Progressbar(toplevel, maximum=100,mode='determinate')
    Generating_Label.pack(side=TOP)
    progress.pack(fill=X)
    progress.start(10)   

def Timer(toplevel):
    sleep(3)
    toplevel.destroy()

def Work():
    toplevel=Toplevel()
    Generate_Invoice(toplevel)
    Timer(toplevel)


window=Tk()
Generate=Button(window, text="Generate invoice",command=Work)
Generate.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: This code does the same thing just differently, it waits for the loop to be over before initialising the window 

`for amount in range(100):
            print amount
            progress["value"]=amount
            if progress["value"]==100:
                toplevel.destroy()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to object orientate complex code like this. Functions make it harder to logically break down.

```
import ttk
from time import sleep
import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.button = ttk.Button(text="Generate Invoice", command=self.start)
        self.button.pack()
        self.labelText = tk.StringVar()
        self.genLabel = ttk.Label(textvariable=self.labelText)
        self.labelText.set(" ")
        self.genLabel.pack()
        self.progress = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient="horizontal",length=150, mode="determinate")
        self.progress.pack()
        self.pr = 0
        self.prmax = 0

    def increase(self):
        self.pr += 5
        self.progress["value"] = self.pr
        if self.pr < self.prmax:
            self.after(100, self.increase)

    def start(self):
        self.progress["value"] = self.pr
        self.prmax = 100
        self.progress["maximum"] = self.prmax
        self.labelText.set("Generating Invoice")
        self.increase()

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

This is based upon someone else's program who I now can't find :P and works how I think you want it. The StringVar() is used to encapsulate the changing of the label text.
*Disclaimer* I am not a good GUI programmer, so this could be pointlessly inefficient.

Comment: This is great, however it is far too complicated with OOP for its use, and I am far to rookie to know how to do it properly

Comment: I found that using the .update() command works, thanks anyway :)